# The value of an range from another page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to have a program with range and at the end I want to give the user all the results.

First of all the range

**Javascript**:

```
 function imgShow(Target)
 {
   for(var i=1; i<=images; i++)
   {
        if(i != Target) 
          document.getElementById('img' + i).style.display = 'none';
        else 
          document.getElementById('img' + i).style.display = 'block';
   }
 }
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="range" id="slider" max="<?php echo ($images*1); ?>" min="1"
   value="1" onchange="imgShow(parseInt(this.value/1));" />
 <output>
  <?php 
    for ($i=0; $i<$images; $i++){
      $image = $files[$i];
      echo '<div id="img' . ($i+1) . '" class="photo" style=""><img src="' . $image . '" /></div>';
    }
  ?>
</output>
```

> ***The code above is GOOD (I just write this so you know which variables I use)***

You see I give the value of the range each time it change an image. Then my problem, I need to put it in a database so I first want to show it in a textarea so the users know what they have scored on the test.

```
 echo '<form action="'. $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] .'" method="post">';
 echo 'Solution:<br>';
 echo '<textarea name="message"></textarea><br>';
 echo '</form>';
```

I guess I need to write something between textarea but I don't know what. Already tried some things. Yes echo's because I do this in the else of "if($_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD]=='POST')".
I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Thats a very strange style of indentation!

Comment: Yeah sorry for that, just a little quick and dirty work :)

Comment: It wasn't a complaint, just a neutral remark. How you indent is essentially your personal preference imo.

Comment: I changed it for stackoverflow, to make it smaller. You know a solution for me?

Answer (score 3):

`textarea` elements have their value inside them and not in a `value` attribute.

i.e.

`<textarea> value here </textarea>`

Comment: Ahn ok, but yeah I still don't know what code (i guess php, maybe js) I need to write there.

Comment: `echo '<textarea name="message">'.htmlentities($_POST['xxx']).'</textarea><br>';`  would be a good example

Comment: I never worked with htmlentities (just have php on secondary school). And what should be in place of the 'xxx' ?

Comment: In which variable do you have what you need displayed in the textbox?

Comment: I don't have one. Thats my problem. I don't know how I need to get the results from another page.